# How do I make a message.channel.send command require two words from the same library? (Python and Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am very new to coding so sorry if my phrasing is wrong, but I have this library of words

```
california_triggers = [
  "California", "california", "Fire", "fire"
]
```

And I want to have the following command trigger only when a message has two of the words in said library

```
    if any(word in msg for word in california_triggers):
      await message.channel.send("California is currently on fire as of "+now_string+".")
```

How would I make "California is on fire as of now" require a trigger of two of the words from california_triggers? I am very sorry as I am new to all of this. And would I require imports that deviate from just the discord library?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site. You have to make an honest attempt, and then ask a **specific question** about your algorithm or technique. If you have no idea where to start, you need to look up a tutorial or talk to a tutor. Stack Overflow is the wrong place to ask for general advice

Comment: I apologize, I'm just trying to make a fun bot for my friends and I and I didn't really have the money to pay someone for this. Thank you for your comments though!

Comment: You don't need to apologise, I'm just pointing out that this isn't the correct way to ask a question here, you can always edit your question to improve it and ask better questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it's not a library of words. [Libraries](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-libraries/#:%7E:text=A%20Python%20library%20is%20a,a%20collection%20of%20core%20modules.) have an entirely different meaning in python. You have a list of words.
Now checking if the msg has two of the words from the list, can be done in several ways.

```py
if len(set(msg.content.split()) & set(california_triggers)) == 2:
    #msg and california have two common words
```

### Explanation:

`msg.content.split()` splits the message by space. i.e into words.
The `&` operation between two sets returns the intersection of the two sets. i.e common words.
We check if the length of common words is 2 and then trigger the if block.

### References:

- [`string.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)
- [intersection of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory))
- [sets in python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)

Note: 
Your question says that you haven't learnt enough python to start coding your own discord bot. I would recommend learning [Python from scratch](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/), and [OOP](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/) specifically for discord.py before you can make an actual bot

Comment: Gotcha, thank you very much, and I'll look into these sources immediately!